# CCScrollView content is still showing out of the bounds of the scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, ccscrollview

I have started making a game using SpriteBuilder and Xcode, and everything is going fine. But then I wanted to add a stats page in the game, and wanted some kind of scrollview. So i dragged in a CCScrollView (in Spritebuilder). And it scrolls just fine.

Problem is : if i set the size of the scrollview to fill the bottom half of the screen, then when i scroll, the content just goes up the screen. It isn't just scrolling inside the 'box' size I set for the scrollview from the start?

Have read about 'clipsToBounds', but I think its not working with a CCScrollView?

Any suggestions for me? And if i haven't descriped it good enough, fell free to ask :-)

Comment: provide some code and explain your goal, then i can help you. as i understand you need a box in your screen to move around just in screen  and dost not go out of screen????

Comment: sorry that I didn't explain it better. My goal was to make a scrollview with stats in just half of the screen (bottom). But when i position the CCScrollView where i want it, then i start scroll, and all the content continues to show on screen (in the top half), even though it i out of the CCScrollviews 'area', where i places it. I would like to be able to scroll content/info in bottom half, and then its only visible in that part, and doesn't scroll out of the area. -Hope its better explained.. :-S